# Applying XSLT recursively

Tags: java, c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to create a xml from another xml using xslt. But I have a problem trying to make it work recursively
This is the original xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <sites>
      <site name="name001" enabled="true" />
      <site name="name003" enabled="false">456</site>
      <env name="name004" enabled="true" />
   </sites>
   <templates>
      <template name="example" SSL="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="abc001">true</other>
               <other name="abc002">
                  <options>
                     <option name="xyz001">567</option>
                     <option name="xyz001">987</option>
                  </options>
               </other>
            </others>
         </props>
      </template>
      <type name="test999" enabled="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="name001" enabled="true">WEBSITE1</other>
               <other name="abc001" />
            </others>
            <install name="xyz">example001</install>
         </props>
      </type>
      <type name="www">
         <props>
            <otherProps>
               <otherProp name="user">anonymous</otherProp>
               <otherProp name="pass" enabled="true" />
               <otherProp name="url" />
            </otherProps>
            <install name="name001">test</install>
         </props>
      </type>
   </templates>
</root>
```

I want to apply xslt to retrieve a similar xml, but only with the elements, which have the attribute conf="true". The parents have to be retrieved too even if they do not have the conf="true attribute"
Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <sites>
      <site name="name001" enabled="true" />
      <env name="name004" enabled="true" />
   </sites>
      <type name="test999" enabled="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="name001" enabled="true">WEBSITE1</other>
         </props>
      </type>
      <type name="www">
         <props>
            <otherProps>
               <otherProp name="pass" enabled="true" />
            </otherProps>
         </props>
      </type>
   </templates>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show any XSLT you have tried, even if it didn't work (You might not be far off the solution, you see!). Also, the question mentions attribute conf="true", but there is no such attribute in your XML. Do you mean enabled="true"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure you ment the enabled attribute that has to be true in order to output some data. Basically you need to copy every element that has that attribute or a descendant with that attribute.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fx="this" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <!-- Removes whitespaces in the output -->
    <xsl:template match="node()"> <!-- Matches every node and checks if it should be printed -->
        <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::node()[@enabled='true']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()"> <!-- We did the check in the node template already so we just want to copy everything -->
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <sites>
      <site name="name001" enabled="true" />
      <site name="name003" enabled="false">456</site>
      <env name="name004" enabled="true" />
   </sites>
   <templates>
      <template name="example" SSL="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="abc001">true</other>
               <other name="abc002">
                  <options>
                     <option name="xyz001">567</option>
                     <option name="xyz001">987</option>
                  </options>
               </other>
            </others>
         </props>
      </template>
      <type name="test999" enabled="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="name001" enabled="true">WEBSITE1</other>
               <other name="abc001" />
            </others>
            <install name="xyz">example001</install>
         </props>
      </type>
      <type name="www">
         <props>
            <otherProps>
               <otherProp name="user">anonymous</otherProp>
               <otherProp name="pass" enabled="true" />
               <otherProp name="url" />
            </otherProps>
            <install name="name001">test</install>
         </props>
      </type>
   </templates>
</root>
```

I get the output:

```
<root>
   <sites>
      <site name="name001" enabled="true"/>
      <env name="name004" enabled="true"/>
   </sites>
   <templates>
      <type name="test999" enabled="true">
         <props>
            <others>
               <other name="name001" enabled="true">WEBSITE1</other>
            </others>
         </props>
      </type>
      <type name="www">
         <props>
            <otherProps>
               <otherProp name="pass" enabled="true"/>
            </otherProps>
         </props>
      </type>
   </templates>
</root>
```

Comment: Good and compact solution but as the template for `match="node()"` solely contains the `xsl:if` you could move the condition of the `test` directly as a predicate into the `match="node()[descendant-or-self::node()[@enabled='true']]"`, no?

Comment: In fact, you need to do as Martin says because `node()` and `text()` both match text nodes with equal priority, which is considered an error. Most processors will take the option to use the last matching template and continue processing, although in theory some could choose to raise an exception.

Comment: I could do as Martin Honnen says, although I had the fear that the excluded nodes would get applied by the default template and output some stuff. I am actually to lazy to try that now, but I will keep that in mind for the next time.
For the second argument I thought that a more specific query like text() would match rather than node(). Probably I should have set a priority to it. Thanks for the feedback :)